# how to inserting a data in to mysql php code

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function create() {
        global $database;

         $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
         $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
         $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
         $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
         $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
         $sql .= "')";


      if($database->query($sql)) {
        $this->id = $database->insert_id();
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

i can't seem to get this function to work, what i want to do is get the data from the form, clean it and add, my description from(_POST) and title from _POST as well and write it to a table. or if there is a better way of getting a data from a form, in my case image gallery. how do i write the sql statement.
i have also tried this

```
$sql ='INSERT INTO photographgallery '.' (filename,type,size,description,title)';
  $sql .='VALUES (\''.$filename.'\', \''.$type.'\',\''.$size.'\',\''.$description.'\',\''.$title.'\')';
```

which didn't work for me. HELP

Comment: If the query is failing, get the error message from the database and look at it - it'll tell you exactly why it's going wrong.

Comment: Echo out the query that the script builds then you will know what is wrong, then you can fix it

Comment: for example if i hard coded it, like this,
$sql = $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
         $sql .="filename,type,size,description,title)
                        VALUES ('";
               $sql .= ",";
               $sql .= "flower','jpg','12','beautiful flower','blue flower')";

it works, i just don't know how to pass the variables.

Comment: So add an `echo $sql;` after you build `$sql` and look at that or show us

Comment: thank you so much that is what i needed, once i echo the $sql, i found out what was wrong, i was sending empty values.

Answer (score 1):

You do seem to want to make your life difficult. This

```
$sql ='INSERT INTO photographgallery '.'     
      (filename,type,size,description,title)';
$sql .='VALUES (\''.$filename.'\', \''.$type.'\',\''.$size.'     
        \',\''.$description.'\',\''.$title.'\')';
```

Can be written much simpler as this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO photographgallery 
                  (filename,type,size,description,title)
        VALUES ('$filename', '$type', '$size', '$description', '$title')";
```

Like this it is so much simpler to see any errors in the syntax

> Using this syntax does leave you open to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and you should use parameterize queries to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this so you get back any errors in your mysql code and the query itself:

```
public function create() {
    global $database;

     $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
     $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (";
     $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
     $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
     $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
     $sql .= "')";


  if($database->query($sql)) {
    $this->id = $database->insert_id();
    return true;
  } else {
    echo $database->error;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $sql;
    return false;
  }
}
```

this should provide you with valuable insight and probably have you able to fix the problem yourself, otherwise you can post the results here.